# How to get the svg in string format of a g element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I would like to know if it is possible to get the contents in a g element of an svg element with jquery or javascript?

```
<svg>
<g><path>...</path></g>
</svg>
<script>
    var contents = $("div").append($("svg g").clone()).html();
</script>
```

This will work normally with the path or any part inside a g element but not the g element itself.  Additionally for some reason if I ran this code:

```
<script>
    var contents = $("div").append($("path").parent().clone()).html();
</script>
```

I can get the contents, but for the project I need to be able to match a g element (in this case a layer) and get it's content.

Comment: Wanted to make a correction the the understanding of this entry, they both work without erroring but the first will get far more than just the g tag, and the second will just get the g tag.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work but there are a couple of problems with your examples.

First you can't use `html()` on an SVG element (see answer here: [Why .html() doesn't work with SVG selectors using jquery ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396372/why-html-doesnt-work-with-svg-selectors-using-jquery)) so it depends what you want to do with the `g` element.

Second you're appending the `g` element to the `div`, but it needs to live inside an `svg` element. So for a page like this:

```
<div>
    <svg>
        <g><path d='m10,10l10,0,0,-10,-10,0'></path></g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

You can clone the `g` element like this:

```
g = $("svg g").clone();
$('svg').append(g);

// Move the cloned square
g.children().first().attr('d', 'm100,100l10,0,0,-10,-10,0');
```

So now you can do whatever you want with the variable **g** in that example (see the linked answer if you need to start editing the inner XML directly rather than use jQuery to modify the contents).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/sXbE3/

To get the string you need to use `XMLSerializer` as described in the linked answer above:

```
var s = new XMLSerializer();
var str = s.serializeToString(g[0]);
console.log(str);
```

Here I'm using `g[0]` to get the DOM element of g. If you just want the contents try `(g.children().first())[0]`. I've updated the fiddle.

However, depending on what you're going to do with the string you might not need to do that. jQuery can modify the elements directly -- it depends what you want to do.

Comment: The way to do that is in the other answer I linked, I've updated the fiddle and edited my answer to show an example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you meant on getting the contents of a g element. I've tried manipulating it using a simple script.

```
    $("[name=getElement]").click(function(){
     $('.getThisElement').hide();
     $("#test"+$(this).val()).show('fast');
```

Try this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qaUqQ/2/) I've created.