# How to get innerHTML from one specify child ELEMENT

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

All:

What I want to do is:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="unwanted"></div>
    <div class="unwanted"></div>
    <svg><rect></rect></svg>
    <div class="unwanted"></div>
<div>
```

How can I get the innerHTML of #container for that svg, so what I get is:

```
"<svg><rect></rect></svg>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the outerHTML of the svg Element but that is not really accessible in this way.
Here

[outerHTML of an SVG element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592417/outerhtml-of-an-svg-element)

is an idea of how to get the svg with content.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you what you want in this case:

```
document.getElementById('container').getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery

```
var container = $("#container").html().find('svg');
// or
 $("#container svg").html();

//return <rect></rect> you can use '<svg>'+container+'</svg>'
```

javascript

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var svg = container.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].innerHTML;

//return <rect></rect> you can use '<svg>'+container+'</svg>'
```

or see @Duopixel's answer on [Why .html() doesn't work with SVG selectors using jquery ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396372/why-html-doesnt-work-with-svg-selectors-using-jquery?)

```
var svg = document.getElementById('svg_root'); // or whatever you call it
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var str = serializer.serializeToString(svg);
```